# Jupiter won't launch from terminal on M1 MacBook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

I recently bought a MacBook Air with M1. After installing `tensorflow` following the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) everything works fine within a virtual environment I set up. However if I just run `jupyter notebook` from the terminal I get the following error message:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/bernardino/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/bernardino/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libzmq.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)`
Google didn't help. Can anyone help out?
Thanks.

Comment: Here's a GitHub post with what looks like the same question.  It has some responses that you might find helpful:  https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/242 - I don't use Jupyter, so I don't know about it specifically, but from what you say I'd think that you'd want to get the Jupyter notebook to use the virtual environment that you say you have that works.